# Why am I not getting the desired output even though no errors?

Tags: c

Program to find the next palindrome to the inputted number

When compiling, only the first part asking input value compiles. After that nothing happens

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n,revNum = 0,remainder,d,revD = 0;

    printf("Enter an non palindromic number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    d = n;

    while (d != revD)
    {
         n += 1;
         d = n;

          while (n != 0)
          {
            remainder = n%10;
            revNum = (revNum * 10) + remainder;
            n = n/10;
          }
         n = d;
         revD = revNum;    
    }
    printf("\nThe nearest palindrome is %d",d);
}
```

Is there something wrong in the way I approached the problem?

Comment: Because a compiler cannot detect logical errors.

Comment: You need to debug this. Use your debugger (investing some time learning how to use it will quickly pay off), or put some `printf`s at strategic points to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to re-initilize `revNum` to 0 in the outer loop.
And of course, as the other answers already point out, the issue is related to a logical mistake. That's why the compiler did not complain at all. 
For instance I figured it out by adding prints inside the inner loop. After some tests I found out that it was working great with immediate predecessors of palindrom numbers (e.g. 43, 98, 100) but it was diverging with other numbers. By printing the internal variables I understood the purpose of `revNum` and that it was supposed to be re-initialized at every iteration of the outer while loop.

```
...
while (d != revD)
{
     n += 1;
     d = n;
     revNum = 0; //ADD THIS

     while (n != 0)
     {
        ...
     }
}
...
```